# How can I do an if last item in jade

Tags: node.js, express, pug, template-engine

As you can see from below I have an array, I would like to remove the svg from the last item in that array when it runs. How might I do this with a condition? Something like if last:item else add svg

```
-navlinks = {"Home":"/Home", "About":"/About", "Store Directory":"/Store-Directory", "Store Page":"/Store-Page", "Events":"/Events",}
ul.navbar-menu
  for val, key in navlinks
    li 
      a(href='#{val}') #{key}
      svg.icon.icon-dots
        use(xlink:href="#icon-dots")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well the thing is, contrary to what you said, `navlinks` is *not* an `Array`, but rather an `Object`. Since `Object` elements do *not* have a numeric index, the notion of `last` does not have much meaning.

However, you could iterate over `Object.keys(navlinks)` which is a proper `Array` with a numeric index. So you could do something like :

```
-navlinks = {"Home":"/Home", "About":"/About", "Store Directory":"/Store-Directory", "Store Page":"/Store-Page", "Events":"/Events",}
ul.navbar-menu
  - each key, index in Object.keys(navlinks)
     li 
        a(href='#{val}')= navlinks[key]
        if index < Object.keys(navlinks).length - 1
          svg.icon.icon-dots
             use(xlink:href="#icon-dots")
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Perhaps on another note, could I get this to work a submenu? So Store Directory might have children of tenants & retailers for example.

Comment: Yes, defintely. Just replace a string value by another object.